can't get my navbar to the top, keeps having a space above or stretches
import SwiftUI

struct UtilitySelectionView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ZStack {
                    // Background color
                    Color.black
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        // Safe area color
                        Color.black
                            .frame(height: geometry.safeAreaInsets.top)
                            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                        
                        // Navbar component
                        Navbar()
                            .offset(y: -geometry.safeAreaInsets.top - 2)
                        
                        Spacer()

                        // Centered Content
                        VStack {
                            Text("Choose your Utility")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                                .padding(.bottom, 20)

                            HStack {
                                NavigationLink(destination: ARSelectionView(utility: .sdge)) {
                                    Image("d_logo")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                                        .background(Color.white)
                                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)) // Rounded edges
                                        .padding(10)
                                }
                                NavigationLink(destination: ARSelectionView(utility: .sce)) {
                                    Image("s_logo")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                                        .background(Color.white)
                                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)) // Rounded edges
                                        .padding(10)
                                }
                                NavigationLink(destination: ARSelectionView(utility: .pge)) {
                                    Image("e_logo")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                                        .background(Color.white)
                                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)) // Rounded edges
                                        .padding(10)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.top, 10) // Adjust the padding as necessary

                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true) // Hide the default navigation bar
        }
    }
}

i tried padding, offsets, and other positioning technieques, i think maybe my layout is off? I am just looking to see how to move it up without stretching out the navbar, so the Hstack that has the image horizontal button and mangifying glass in it is the navbar that I'd like to modify and move upwards -

Note, NavigationView is deprecated use NavigationStack instead

Thanks so much @workingdogsupportUkraine! that was the issue!!!!!
